# Python- flask digest auth with POSTMAN

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, rest, flask

So, I am trying to understand the digest authentication implementation with Python- Flask.
I did a simple test, I took the below code from the documentation,

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_httpauth import HTTPDigestAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret key here'
auth = HTTPDigestAuth()

users = {
    "john": "hello",
    "susan": "bye"
}

@auth.get_password
def get_pw(username):
    if username in users:
        return users.get(username)
    return None

@app.route('/', methods=['HEAD'])
@auth.login_required
def index():
    return "Hello, %s!" % auth.username()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The code runs.
I paste this URL(host:port) in same in POSTMAN(head method), it always returns 401.
I am lost and am trying to get it work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If GET is present, Flask automatically adds support for the HEAD method and handles HEAD requests according to the HTTP RFC. Likewise, OPTIONS is automatically implemented for you. So basically remove HEAD and see if you "GET" response in postman.

Comment: @RajVerma I changed it to GET and it still didn't work. :(.  However, I was able to get it to work now without having a single clue as to what I did. I will paste the complete script I used to test my REST client here. It should be helpful for someone with the same requirement.

Comment: Wierd, did you get to capture anything from the debug logs when this was not working??

Comment: The only thing I could see in the logs were client info and the error message with code 401. When it started working, it returned 200. There was nothing else in the log, I changed nothing :(

Comment: I was incorrect, I didnt get it to work, I accidentally commented out the @auth.login_required

Comment: Share you code repo, git/bitbucket ??

Comment: please find the code here https://github.com/MagnusRox/Sample/blob/main/digestApp.py

Answer (score 0):

OK so here is what the problem is, the URL works fine in the browser but not in POSTMAN.

1. This is happening due to the name resolution in your case, e.g. **9mxlhm2**
   You need to make sure that it resolved that name, try and see if you can ping that name mentioned or else easiest fix just use **`**0.0.0.0**`**, if this is local.
2. Make sure the authorization info is mentioned when you are doing a HTTP request via postman. Under the request section there will be a Authorization section. See this image as an example.[image]
3. To reproduce the problem i used localhost but it didn't work and it gives me an error with 401, as soon as i try 0.0.0.0 in the GET request via postman, it starts to work again. Hope this fixes your problem. Although the hostname for me works(as in my own hostname, e.g rajlocal)

Comment: Thanks or the response. But it still doesnt work for me. I tried with both localhost and 0.0.0.0, it still doesnt run. I have tried localhost before, even then it doesnt work. I am not sure what could be the difference between our setup. Just to be sure, I will try this in another machine and get back

Comment: Edit: It doest work in a remote machine either.

Comment: Sure try it out and let me know which os are you on? This shouldn’t cause any issues within postman as long as you do not have any dns issues identifying the host and auth enabled in postman. The same code works for me on remote and local both.

Comment: I am on Windows 10(local) and another was Windows Server 2016. I can make this code work this BasicAuth and without any authentication, somehow digest authentication fails consistently.

Comment: And you are choosing digest in postman on left under authorisation??

Comment: Yea I am. I have changed nothing. I have just pasted the URL, and added authorisation. Is there something else I should add to make this work?

Comment: Well as i mentioned it to do with postman not recognising the hostname, try changing it with the ip address see if that works.